# How to override an application's single instance limit in Windows?

Tags: winapi, ipc, mutex, detours

I am trying to override the singe instance limit of an application for which I don't have the source. I know that the app is using the good ol' trick of using CreateMutex to determine whether there is another instance running. (If the mutex is created successfully it proceeds, if getlasterror says that the mutex has been created it quits immediately). I found that through sniffing the Win32 api calls.
I thought using Detours would do the trick, but it doesn't quite work out. I am intercepting CreateMutexW, but for some reason, it doesn't catch the first four calls to it. (Again I know what these calls are by sniffing win32 calls and looking at the name of the mutexes). I do get the fifth one intercepted, but the one I actually want to intercept is the first one.

I am using detours through the sample application withdll. I wonder if the problem is that detours is kicking in too late or because of some kind of protection these calls may have. Is detours the best approach? Perhaps using something else may be a better idea?

Comment: Usually the developers have a good reason to prevent their software from running twice at the same time...

Comment: That's pretty obvious, but I wouldn't go as far as to do interception for no good reason.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reasons for the situation you describe. Here are the most probable of them:

1. The CreateMutexW call you need to catch occurs within the DllMain
   method of one of the DLLs that are imported by the process, and you
   are using the DetoursCreateProcessWithDll() function to inject your
   code. Detours injects your DLL by placing it at the end of the
   process executable import list, and hence all the DLLs that are
   imported by the process would be loaded and initialized within the
   process prior to yours. In order to overcome this, try using
   CreateProcess(CREATE_SUSPENDED) and CreateRemoteThread()-based
   injection, although this method raises its own challenges.
2. The API that is used in the first call is different. Have you tried
   overriding CreateMutexExW? Are you sure ANSI methods call Unicode
   ones?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Haven't looked back at that problem for a while. What I was thinking is just to destroy the Mutex before the second copy start (just closing the handle should do I guess). However your approach seems much cleaner.
I am only overiding CreateMutexW, do you mean that I should override CreateMutexA as well? According to an API sniffer I was using the call was to CreateMutexW